# PHP Problems related to Undefined index error

Tags: php

Can you help me with this errors. I am actually trying to generate an invoice. However, my generated invoice having some problems as you can see as the image below.

[image: The errors in my invoice]

Here is the image of my coding.

[image: Error in line 38]

Comment: print_r($_GET); and know that there is index like oid ?

Comment: paste your code here instead of image

Answer (score 0):

```
$oid = ( isset($_GET['oid']) ) ? $_GET['oid'] : null;
```

Also I believe line 38 should come before line 37. bindParam calls a variable defined after it.

Answer (score 0):

You use variable $oid which it's data is `$_GET['oid']`, in your query before you actually declare/store data to it.

Move line 38 -> `$oid = $_GET['oid']`; after opening try/catch, that means to line 29, before stating the query. You should implement @fie answer too, to be sure that `$oid` is not null and that data actually exists.

Also something is wrong with line 73 but we can't see it.